# About noetherian commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I've trouble with understanding some details about noetherian rings.

For example, I don't understand why this theorem is wrong:

> A ring $R$ is noetherian if and only if it's finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra.

My proof: the implication "noetherian $\Rightarrow$ finitely generated" is standard and obvious. The inverse implication also looks rather simple to me: cannot we say that finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra is quotient $\mathbb Z[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ / $\mathfrak I$ ($\mathfrak I$ is ideal), so by Hilbert basis theorem it's a quotient of the noetherian ring, so it's noetherian itself?

Can somebody help me and explain to me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should rethink the implication "noetherian $\Rightarrow$ finitely generated". Noetherianness only implies that every ideal is finitely generated *as an ideal*, but not necessarily as a ring. Every field is noetherian, for example, but an uncountable field cannot be finitely generated. In fact, no *infinite* field is finitely generated as a ring ; see [If a ring is Noetherian, then every subring is finitely generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94952/if-a-ring-is-noetherian-then-every-subring-is-finitely-generated) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've already found a mistake in this implication...

Comment: Could you say me, please, is it true that a submodule of a finitely generated module over finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra is finitely generated? Is it true for quotients?

Comment: It is easy to see for quotients, and for submodules, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809381/any-submodule-of-any-finitely-generated-r-module-is-finitely-generated-if-r).

Comment: Thank you for your attention and help.